# getroomlists ews not returning any data

Tags: outlook

I am trying to get all rooms available and  status of the room using Microsoft exchange service . Below code is used to get the room list. But this is returning zero room, although I have 8 rooms.

```
 EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = serviceData.GetRoomLists();
```

authenticated to an Exchange server and have acquired an ExchangeService object named serviceData. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [How to: Get room lists by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643730%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in MSDN which explains how to get a list of all the room lists in your organization or a single room list from an Exchange server by using the EWS Managed API or EWS.

Comment: When using ervice.GetRoomLists(), it returns 0 records

Comment: Wow, great help there Eugene. Did you every find a resolution to this sunil?